# How do I embed a video in Facebook a la Hulu and YouTube?

Tags: facebook, video

Can anyone explain how (or point to sample code) to embed a video into a user's Facebook feed?  This would be identical functionality to what the "Share on Facebook" button does on YouTube and Hulu.  The video would be hosted on my site, and presumably viewed using a Flash-based video player.  I am particularly interested to know how this can be accomplished through the new Facebook Graph API, or if that's not possible, through the old REST API.  Thanks!